# Python `select.select` vs `asyncio.wait`. Which to use?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio

Both of these functions can be used to wait for the first of a group of files to become readable. `select` uses a UNIX syscall; `asyncio.wait` uses green threads. What are the theoretical pros and cons of each approach? Do they use the same underlying primitives (in particular, does `asyncio.wait` somehow figure out that it's waiting on file descriptors and call `select`)?

```py
import select
devices = ["/dev/input/event6", "/dev/input/event3"]
files = [open(device) for device in devices]
first_fileno = select.select([file.fileno() for file in files], [], [])[0][0]
print([file.name for file in files if file.fileno() == first_fileno][0])
```

```py
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import contextlib

async def read_and_return(file):
    contents = await file.read(1)
    return file, contents

async def main(devices):
    async with contextlib.AsyncExitStack() as stack:
        files = [await stack.enter_async_context(aiofiles.open(device, "rb")) for device in devices]
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(read_and_return(file)) for file in files]
        completed, incompleted = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        file, contents = list(completed)[0].result()
        print(file.name)

devices = ["/dev/input/event6", "/dev/input/event3"]
asyncio.run(main(devices))
```

Comment: `asyncio` should be more portable, `select.select()` on Windows only works on sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Asyncio is meant to abstract away the usage of mechanisms like "select" and the need for callbacks. The gain of using asyncio is being able to write collaborative concurrent code, which will just run your code as you wrote it, with no suden state changes, and only give a chance for things to run in parallel or in the background at explicit places.

The `select` call is one mechanism that is meant to work with checking the readiness of something explicitly, and then handling it - is more "low level" than asyncio.

So the idea is that one will use the higher abstraction: asyncio mechanisms, to write single threaded concurrent code, as the other way one will be rewriting code which asyncio already is designed for, and designed to accommodate in an efficient way, not only "select" based I/O, but also a series of other mechanisms for concurrent programing.

The exception should be if you are *only* needing the `select.select` call, and the remaining of your program has no needs for one-thread concurrency, and using asyncio would make it more complicated (like in having to search for specific async libraries when you already have working synchronous code).

The rule of thumb should be to use async mechanisms - either native asyncio, or an alternative implementation like "trio" - https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: But I don't think the async solution under-the-hood uses `select`. I could be wrong, but I don't see how it would be implemented since you can put arbitrary awaitables in the `asyncio.await`. Are they using different primitives? I've updated the question to add my confusion.

Comment: asyncio will use "select" or the similar working "epoll" or "kqueue"  - whatever is the default call for Python in the platform for the network calls it implements. "aiofiles" on the other hand, is a 3rdy party library which, last I checked, did use multi-threading code for file access - maybe they found it to be more efficient than select, maybe it was simply easier for the library author. On Linux one would be better looking for an async-file access library wrapping around IO_Uring these days.

Comment: How would `asyncio.wait` use `epoll` with arbitrary awaitables?